# Java - adding person to a linked list via text UI

Tags: java, user-interface, text, linked-list

When trying to add a person, it just says null pointer error at `personList.AddPersonSort`.  Please help.

```
    import java.util.*;

    /**
    *en meny
    * @author Henning
    */

    public class Menutext
    {

    private PersonList personList;

     /**
     * mainMenu()
     * skriver ut hovedmeny
     * @param   none
     * @return  none
     */
    public void mainMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("*********************************");
        System.out.println(" Main Menu");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" 1: Add a person");
        System.out.println(" 2: Print all the persons");
        System.out.println(" 3: End Program");
        System.out.println(" Please choose an option! ");
    }    

    public void question()
    {   System.out.println("Would you like to proceed or quit?");
        System.out.println("To proceed enter 9.");
        System.out.println("If you wish to quit enter 0.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        switch (sc.nextInt())   
        {       
            case 0:     
            System.out.println ("Thank you and godbye.");
            break;      
            case 9:     
            System.out.println ("Please proceed.");
            new Menutext();
            break;
            default:
            System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
            break;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Menu()
     * Starter systemet. Dette will skrive ut en velkomst beskjed og starte
     * en dialog med brukeren via en meny inntil brukeren avslutter dialogen
     * @param   none
     * @return  none
     */
    public Menutext()
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner ( System.in );

        mainMenu();
            switch ( sc.nextInt() )
            {
                case 1:
                  newPersonMenu();
                  //question();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("All the people in the list:\n");
                   personList.toString();
                   question();
                    break;



                default:
                System.out.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
                question();
                break;
            }   


    }

    /**
     * newPersonMenu()
     * legger til en person
     * @param   none
     * @return  none
     */
    public void newPersonMenu()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please register a new person");
        System.out.print(" Please write firstname: ");
        String  fn = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print(" Please write surname: ");
        String  sn = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print(" Please write birthyear: ");
        int bir = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print(" Please write deathyear (or 0 if still alive): ");
        int det = sc.nextInt();

        //System.out.print(" You entered: " fn + " " + sn " (" + bir + "-" + det + ").");

         personList.addPersonSort(fn, sn, bir, det);


        question();
    }   



    public class PersonList extends DNodeList<Person>
    {


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LinkedListEvents
     */
    public PersonList()
    {
        super();
    }

     /**
     * lager en string representasjon av listen
     */

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String listPerson = "";
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            listPerson = "Persons:\n";
            DNode<Person> hRef = header.getNext();
            while (hRef != trailer)
            {
                listPerson += hRef.getIndex() + "  " + hRef.getElement().getFirstName() + "  " +    hRef.getElement().getSurname() + "(" + hRef.getElement().getbirthyear() + " - " + hRef.getElement().getdeathyear() + ")";
                hRef = hRef.getNext();
                if (hRef != trailer)
                {
                    listPerson += "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listPerson = "No people registered.";
        }
        return listPerson;
    }




    /**
     * legger til en person etter fÃ¸dsels Ã¥r
     *
     * @param fn fornavn
     * @param sn etternavn
     * @param bir fÃ¸dselsÃ¥r
     * @param det Ã¥ret personen dÃ¸de
     */
    public void addPersonSort(String fn, String sn, int bir, int det)
    {
        DNode<Person> hRef = null;
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            addLast(new Person(fn, sn, bir, det));
        }
        else
        {
            hRef = getFirst();
            while (hRef.getNext().getElement().getbirthyear() < bir && hRef.getNext() != trailer)
            {
                hRef = hRef.getNext();
            }
            addAfter(hRef, new Person(fn, sn, bir, det));
        }
    }




    /**
     *
     */
    public Person searchPerson(String fn)
    {
        return search(fn).getElement();
    }

    /**
     * sÃ¸ker etter hendelse
     *
     * @param desc hendelsen vi sÃ¸ker etter
     * @return hendelsen om den er der
     */
    public DNode<Person> search(String fn)
    {
        DNode<Person> hRef = header;
        DNode<Person> e = null;
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            do
            {
                hRef = hRef.getNext();
            }
            while (!hRef.getElement().getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(fn));
            if (hRef != trailer && hRef.getElement().getFirstName().equals(fn))
            {
                e = hRef;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No such person.");
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    /**
     * sorterer listen etter Ã¥rstall
     */
    public void sortPersons()
    {
        if (size() <= 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        DNode<Person> pivot;
        DNode<Person> ins;
        DNode<Person> end = (DNode<Person>) getFirst();
        while(end != getLast())
        {
            pivot = end.getNext();
            removeElement(pivot);
            ins = end;
            while (hasPrev(ins) && ins.getElement().getbirthyear() > pivot.getElement().getbirthyear())
            {
                ins = ins.getPrev();
            }
            addAfter(ins, pivot.getElement());
            if (ins == end)
            {
                end = end.getNext();
            }
        }
        indexNodes();
    }


    }

@Override

public String toString()
    {
        String listPerson = "";
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            listPerson = "Persons:\n";
            DNode<Person> hRef = header.getNext();
            while (hRef != trailer)
            {
                listPerson += hRef.getIndex() + "  " + hRef.getElement().getFirstName() + "  " + hRef.getElement().getSurname() + "(" + hRef.getElement().getbirthyear() + " - " + hRef.getElement().getdeathyear() + ")";
                hRef = hRef.getNext();
                if (hRef != trailer)
                {
                    listPerson += "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listPerson = "No people registered.";
        }
        return listPerson;
    }
```

It doesn't give any people registered after I add 1 person in the text UI.

Answer (score 2):

In Menutext you should initialize your personList before use.

```
private PersonList personList = new PersonList();
```

Comment: thank you! no more nullpointer. but now i only get " no person registered" when i try to print it with the toString method i added above

Comment: @user733299 - stacker answered your question, please accept it, as you said it solved the problem. If you have another problem, you're welcome to post it as a separate question. Please try to format your code next time a little bit more, so the eyes of those trying to help you won't pop out :)

Comment: @user733299 To debug your code you should set breakpoints or trace execution using single step and watch your variables. If you don't work with an IDE you could at least add a few System.out.println to see which variables are null.